# How do you morph a skill?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

While playing Elder Scrolls Online, I get a message saying skill X can now be morphed.

What does morphing a skill do? How do I go about morphing said skill?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you recall which skill that is ready to morph, grab a skill point and find it in your skill tree (you'll only be able to tell if you have an available skill point). Once you have located your skill that is ready to morph on your skill tree you will see 3 diamond shapes in an arrow formation (I would screenshot it but I don't have a skill point right now, I'll update later).

Now that you have located your skill, click these three diamonds. It will give you a small pop up box giving you two different choices that will be two of three things typical (that I have seen). You will either get to choose; more damage, more powerful spell (as in the effects of the spell will get stronger), or some sort of CC. Obviously each spell is different so you will get different types of choices with each skill.

Remember once you have chosen to morph a skill it consumes a skill point.

Comment: some reason screenshot is uploading.